# How to access iCloud as core data for iCloud is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud

I am working on an app using core data as I thought I could use sync functionality provided by core data for iCloud for syncing data between iPad and iPhone, now it is deprecated.

I came across CloudKit but it is mainly to create and manage data that can be consumed by *community of end users* but not just one like chat apps. My app is only for *single user* so that user can sync their data between their apple eco system devices.

I am new to iOS development so it would be helpful to know which technology will meet my requirements.

In short, can you please suggest what should I use

1. If have to store data on phone for offline use
2. Then sync it across devices if user have say iPhone, iPad, and iWatch

P.S. Can you please suggest something that doesn't need the user to be signed into iCloud while saving the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the videos from the latest WWDC.
Here is something about [CloudKit Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/231/) and [whats new in cloud kit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/226/)
CloudKit really have some nice out of the box solutions and you dont have to bother about security. Also the newest functionality enables you to use notifications for synchronising apps using the same apple id and even beyond, as the user can now opt to share certain data.

Depending how much data you are syncing, NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default() is also an option. But only for very less data

Comment: I agree with that but does the user need to be logged into iCloud while saving data? If it is then it would be a problem if the user is not logged in

Comment: That is true, but that us also true for all the other apple aps, such as photos, messages, pages, etc.

Comment: My app provides images and text in the app itself, which the user choses and they don't need to interact with outside environment, so I am thinking off designing it in  a way that they are alway available offline. Later sync it with iPad or iWatch. To meet these requirements do you think Core Data + CloudKit will do the job as Core Data + iCloud is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, but there are a few pitfalls to be aware of. I would save images to photos. In that way you get the all the synchronisation and image handling for free from apple. The images will load very quickly in you app. Check out the Photos API for that. You can make a special library for your apps photos and the are automatically distributed to all the devices. Text is perfect for iCloud

Comment: like what? Are there any third party tools you can suggest that I could use for my requirements that doesn't have hard time getting through app store review

Comment: Sorry hit the enter before I was finished. The rest is there now

Comment: 3rd party I would look at Azure and their "mobile app service", where you get a framework for sync and everything. It is not free though! But scales indefinitely.

Comment: But I cannot use iCloud as it is deprecated, so I cannot sync CoreData with iCloud, so I need to write code to make CloudKit API calls? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The CoreData/iCloud integration is deprecated in iOS 10 / macOS Sierra, and there is no replacement (at least so far).

Way forward so far :

- Use third party framework such as Ensembles : http://www.ensembles.io
- Use CloudKit, which can be used for that. See this for a help : https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/cloudkit-core-data-nsoperations-introduction/

Note that CoreData/iCloud integration will still be working for some time in the future. Apps that are using it will not suddenly stop working.

Comment: But do these both require iCloud as the user need to have been signed in to  iCloud to save the data?

Comment: @learner122 CloudKit does require te user to have an iCloud account. It handles all the security aspects for you. ICloud in itself is not deprecated. Only Core Data integration framework. For Ensembles, I don't know. But Ensembles allows the user to store the sync data to iCloud or Dropbox or other service. So my guess is that it uses the chosen service security and authentication.

Comment: So I am thinking of going with Core Data + CloudKit for my requirements as mentioned in my edited question. What do you think?

Comment: I guess it is a solution that will work. However this will need some efforts. And most probably some trials an error. But everybody is left in that situation for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

Apple just released a new container for Core Data that can sync across devices with iCloud.

Get started here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit

Note, this requires iOS 13.